PyTorch type for dataset with length
I am creating a meta-dataset that combines data from multiple input datasets.
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, IterableDataset

class MetaDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, regular_dataset: Dataset, iterable_dataset: IterableDataset):
        self.regular_dataset = regular_dataset
        self.iterable_dataset = iterable_dataset
        pass # Do other stuff...

I got a type warning when I tried to access len(self.regular_dataset) from within MetaDataset
It turns out that the PyTorch type definition for Dataset intentionally doesn't include __len__. Therefore, I have to build my own type:
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, IterableDataset

class DatasetWithLength(Dataset):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        pass

class MetaDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, regular_dataset: DatasetWithLength, iterable_dataset: IterableDataset):
        self.regular_dataset = regular_dataset
        self.iterable_dataset = iterable_dataset
        pass # Do other stuff...

But now, I get a Expected type 'DatasetWithLength', got 'FirstDataset' instead warning when I try to do this:
foo = MetaDataset(
    FirstDataset(),
    FirstIterableDataset(),
)

How do I correctly define the type of a PyTorch Dataset that has the length property?

You need to define a generic type, so that you don't need to extend from DatasetWithLength.
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class _DatasetWithLength(Dataset):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=_DatasetWithLength)
DatasetWithLength = Generic[T]

